# Force HTTPS on my website doesn´t work

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, routes

I have a problem with forcing HTTPS on my domain, my htaccess file on root of the web has following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$    $1.php    [L]
```

This works perfectly on http and https protocols, but website is not forced to https, when visiting over http. So I added later to my htaccess code that force https, and the result was following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$    $1.php    [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But the website stopped work at all. Do you know why? And how can I fix it? Thank You so much.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a deep understanding of `.htaccess` files, but this worked for me and might help you too. Handle the redirect to `https` first, then remove the `.php` from the filename.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn´t work as well. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Sorry. It works on my site. Are there other lines in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Just ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Nothing more